# Using jquery or pure javascript for copy the style of a dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to know the best way to accomplish the following task:
Using jquery or pure javascript code for copy the style of one dom element to another.

example:

```
// css file
div.myClass {
    color: red;
}
```

---

```
// html file
<div class="otherClass">
 no style
</div>
```

---

```
// js script
var propertyName = color;
$("div.otherClass").css( propertyName , function () {
    return $("div.otherClass").css(propertyName);
}  )
```

The js script works but I would like to take the propertyName automatically. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/3AYGg/) for your question from another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element).

Answer (score 1):

why not append the same class from one to the other?

```
$("div.otherClass").addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not clear in my question. This way it does not work in my case because renaming the class I will bind some event which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace the style properties of that element then you could also do something like this

```
$("div.otherClass").removeClass("otherClass").addClass("myClass");
```

this will first remove the class otherClass and then ad myclass to the element

otherwise Joseph's answer would work best

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not clear in my question. This way it does not work in my case because renaming the class I will bind some event which I don't want.